# Can't figure out how to boot from sd card using GNU GRUB

Tags: linux, system-installation, grub

I tried to install kubuntu on my laptop (Acer Spin) and got an error of "unable to install GRUB" occurred and I had to restart the computer. I tried to turn it back on and use a new flash of the iso and it immediately opened to a screen with the Acer logo and GNU GRUB open at the top... There is a grub command line and I'm not really sure on how to proceed. I tried to exit and it said, "System BootOrder not found." I believe I have found the sd card by using ls, but am still unsure of how to boot into it.

Comment: UEFI system? If so you must partition in advance and have an ESP on that drive. But if Ubuntu installer, it only wants ESP on first drive. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1296065/dual-booting-w10-ubuntu-with-2-separate-ssds-in-uefi-mode/1296153#1296153